# como ejecuto dos procedimientos al tiempo en php

Tags: php, mysql

necesito ejecutar dos procedimientos. la cuestion es que solo me funciona el primero y el segundo no funciona. el segundo esta dentro de un for ya que necesito meter un array en el segundo procedimiento.

```
$sql = "call spIngresarFactura('" . $fecha. "','" . $id. "');";

        $resultados = mysqli_query($this->conexion, $sql);
        $d = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $idfactura=$d["id"]; 

        for ($i=0; $i < count($carrito) ; $i++) {
            $carrosolo=$carrito[$i];
$sql2 = "call spIngresardetalle('" . $idfactura. "','" . $carrosolo[0]. "','" . $carrosolo[2]. "','" . $carrosolo[1]. "');";
            mysqli_query($this->conexion, $sql2);
        }
```

Comment: deja de ejecutarse que quiere decir?

Comment: solo se ejecuta el primero. El segundo no hace nada. no funciona

Comment: y entra al for del segundo? existe $carrito? tiene algo?

Comment: si carrito existe llega un array lleno y todo. el procedimiento es lo que no se ejecuta. es mas si borro el de arriba el de abajo funciona.

Comment: ¿Qué haces ese sp? ¿Por qué no usas transacciones para esto? ¿Revisaste el log de errores?

Comment: ese es el nombre del procedimiento almacenado. lo unico que hace es insertar datos.

Comment: @A.Cedano es mas experto que yo en esto.. pero puede ser que la conexion siga ocupada con el SP de arriba y por eso no ejecuta el de abajo? necesitara otra conexion distinta?

Comment: hay esta el misterio por que ambos funcionan. pero juntos no

Comment: No me dices nada del log de errores ¿?  Si aprendes a usarlo, créeme, te ahorrarás horas de depuración. O, pon un control de errores, en cualquier caso deberías hacerlo.  Algo así más o menos: **`if ( mysqli_query($this->conexion, $sql2) ) { echo "Registro insertado".PHP_EOL; } else { echo "Error: ". mysqli_error($this->conexion).PHP_EOL; }`** Aunque lo correcto en estos casos es usar transacciones.