# ¿Por que mi query en PHP solo inserta el primer registro del array?

Tags: php, stored-procedure

la setencia solo se ejecuta una vez y no multiples veces. a pesar de que el query esta dentro de for. alguna idea ?

```
$idfactura=59; 

        if ($idfactura>0) {

        for ($i=0; $i < count($carrito) ; $i++) {
            $carrosolo=$carrito[$i];
            echo $idfactura;
            echo $carrosolo[0];
            echo $carrosolo[2];
            echo $carrosolo[1];

            $sql2 = "call spIngresardetalle('" . $idfactura. "','" . $carrosolo[0]. "','" . $carrosolo[2]. "','" . $carrosolo[1]. "');";
            mysqli_query($conexion, $sql2);

        }

        }
```

lo que contiene carrito es esto y lo extraigo con el for para insertarlo en el query espero que con este quede un poco mas claro
lo que contiene carrito es esto y lo extraigo con el for para insertarlo en el query espero que con este quede un poco mas claro

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "21"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [3]=>
    string(7) "Vestido"
    [4]=>
    string(5) "90000"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "21"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [3]=>
    string(7) "Vestido"
    [4]=>
    string(5) "90000"
  }
}
```

Comment: Rápidamente se me ocurre que puede que: 1. La tabla donde guardas esta información tiene un índice (`Unique`) que evita que los demás datos se guarden 2. Que `count($carrito)` sea igual a 1. Habría que ver el detalle del `SP`, la estructura de la tabla y el contenido de la variable `$carrio`.

Comment: Me parece que [planteaste el problema ya ayer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/297668/29967), allí te hicimos algunas recomendaciones, incluso te puse un ejemplo de código de control de errores para ver qué error da exactamente... ¿no hiciste nada al respecto?

Comment: Revisa cuandos items de array te reporta primero la variabla $carrito, este es el primer paso para ver porque se ejecuta una sola vez, lo otro sera revisar el procedure spIngresardetalle()

Comment: ahi esta lo que contiene la variable solo inserta el primer dato

Comment: @AlbertoJulioArceEscolar, ¿podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar la estructura de la tabla con sus indices?

Comment: Como ya sugerí en la otra pregunta, introduce un control de errores: `if ( mysqli_query($conexion, $sql2) ) { echo "Registro insertado".PHP_EOL; } else { echo "Error: ". mysqli_error($conexion).PHP_EOL; }` así sabrás qué error da exactamente.

Comment: segui tu consejo de ayer pero no reporta errores

Comment: ¿Si haces eso qué ocurre, imprime siempre `"Registro insertado"`, no imprime nada nunca, ...?

Comment: y con respecto a lo de UNIQUE no lo tiene asignado la tabla

Comment: se inserta el primer registro de ahi para adelante no inserta mas nada

Comment: el procedimianto funciona a la perfeccion en mysql lo ejecuto y si inserta los datos el problema este es en php

Comment: `$sql2 = "call spIngresardetalle('" . $idfactura. "','" . $carrosolo[0]. "','" . $carrosolo[2]. "','" . $carrosolo[1]. "');";
            mysqli_query($conexion, $sql2);`  es como si esto se ejecutara una sola vez aclaro que estoy trabajando con api rest no se si eso influye

Comment: Lo más rápido aquí es ir a log de errores para revisar que es lo que pasa. En el array se ven datos idénticos, por lo que puede estar saltando una restricción `UNIQUE`, aunque dices que no tienes esa restricción en la tabla. Otra cosa que puedes hacer es un `var_dump` de la ejecución a ver si hay alguna pista: `$rs=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql2); var_dump($rs);` Sea como sea, aprende a manejar el log de errores, ya habrías encontrado el problema, desde ayer.

Comment: Pero sí estás viendo haciendo bien el ciclo, puede que por alguna razón se pare

Comment: Yo reproduje el problema y me funciona perfectamente. Puse una restricción y me imprime el mensaje de error en los casos en que se viole la restricción. Si no te funciona, debes verificar si la estructura del array es correcta, si los datos se crean bien realmente: `'" . $idfactura. "','" . $carrosolo[0]. "','" . $carrosolo[2]. "','" . $carrosolo[1]. "'` o si hay alguna incoherencia en la SP. ¿Podrías mostrar la SP en la pregunta? ¿Podrías revisar qué índices/restricciones tiene la tabla realmente?